Get "preco" value of the table and += in total textbox windows forms
I want to get the "preco" value and put into "total" textbox.
and when I click on "confirmar" button add as a new line to the second grid.
Windows Forms
private void formatargridProdutoVendido()
{
    gridProdutoVendido.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
    gridProdutoVendido.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Código de Barras";
    gridProdutoVendido.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Nome";
    gridProdutoVendido.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Preço";

    gridProdutoVendido.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}

private void btnconfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.abrirconexao();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codigo=" + txtCodigo.Text;
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con.con);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    gridProdutoVendido.DataSource = dt;
    con.fecharconexao();

    formatargridProdutoVendido();
}


Bind your grids to bindinglists. Then you can simply copy an item from one list to the other. See also: Binding List to DataGridView in WinForm.
